# 80s Short story or novella written from a cat's point of view as they cross a parking lot

Tags: story-identification, humor

Short story or Novella from a pulp magazine in the 80's written from a cat's point of view, involved crossing a dead expanse (a parking lot) and a fear of castration by a human (My human would NEVER do that to me). Long shot, I know. Astounding SF or Asimov's maybe?

Comment: Maybe something by Fritz Leiber? His Gummitch the Cat stories appeared as late as 1983 in F&SF.

Comment: Who are "they" that are crossing the parking lot with the cat? The cat's human owners, or a pack of cats?

Comment: Could this story/novella eventually have been incorporated into Tailchaser's Song by Tad Williams?